# Google Translate API invoked too many time in one day error message. Bypass this limitation?

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently published a Google Add-on who translates Google Spreadsheets cells
*(Add-on link :* https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/translate-my-sheet/ikbffjfknllcipddomhgdhcedikhiaga*)*

For each cell, a request is sent to the Google Translate API to translate the content.

Many users are performing a fuly sheet translation with many thousands lines and they encoured the following error message : 'invoked too many time in one day message'. *(I think the limitation is 20,000 by day)*

**Someone knows if it's possible to bypass this limitation please?**

Thank's in advance, Joey.

Comment: The [default limit](https://cloud.google.com/translate/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2015-q1-cloud-northam-us-gce-bkws-freetrial-en#pricing-calc) should be 2M per day. See [*Can I increase my translation limits?*](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#pricing) to increase your quota.

Comment: Thank's for your solution.